# Is it possible to have persistent memory allocated to a process?

Tags: c, linux

Suppose process A allocates some memory in which it stores some data. Let's say it is a set of key -> value pairs. It is expensive to create these key -> value pairs. So, I want to allocate memory such that even if process A dies for some reason when it is restarted it should be able to access this data in RAM. I understand I can store the data to a file and read it back when A restarts. I want to explore if there are other methods available if the amount of memory available is not an issue.

Is there a mechanism (api) to allocate memory such that it is pinned in memory until freed. If not, is it possible to achieve this by employing shared memory techniques. For example 2 process allocate and share the same memory and so even if one process dies the memory is not freed because the other is still alive. When the dead process is restarted can it regain access to that shared memory? If yes how?

Finally if this is not possible I am curious why the kernel does not provide such a mechanism?

Comment: Memory mapping a file seems to fit what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can use memory-mapped files, or an in-memory database like Redis or MemCached.

Comment: The man page for mmap under the description for munmap() says "The region is also automatically unmapped when the process is terminated."  This is what I don't want.

Comment: `mmap` with a file *will* store the data into that file. Also, *everything* is unmapped when the process ends.

Comment: @Reep - yes it is unmapped automatically, but the file need not be deleted, and you can map an existing file - so you can remap the file on restart.  That is not to say you will not loose data or it will be consistent - that is not possible to determine in the event of an uncontrolled abort.  The trick there is not to write buggy code!  Not freeing the file on failure may be a bad idea, since there is no guarantee that a user will choose to restart the process - when would such memory be released?

Comment: @Reep I don't think that unmap means what you think it does. It just means that the connection between the file and the memory goes away.  Next time that your process starts up, it just needs to create the mapping from the file to memory again.  Note that this is not a free operation, and may or may not be cheaper than your existing mechanism to recreate the key value pairs.  The alternative is to create a daemon that is always running and it's only responsibility is to maintain the mapping.  Note that when multiple processes share the same mapping you will have to handle permission issues.

Comment: Does the data need to survive reboot, or is it ok to regenerate it then? If regen on reboot is ok, I would concentrate on removing crashing bugs, rather than add complex (meaning even more ways for program to crash) data storage with shared memory...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  What you're looking for is called `Shared Memory segments`.  Run `man 7 shm_overview` to get the overview but basically it's:

```
shm_open - allocate or re-open a shared memory segment (POSIX)
shmget - allocate a shared memory segment (System V)
shmat - attaches to a shared memory segment (System V)
shmdt - detaches from a shared memory segment (System V)
shm_unlink - remove the shared memory segment (POSIX)
```

If you have a copy of "Advanced UNIX Programming" 2nd edition the chapter "Advanced Interprocess Communication" cover this in more detail in sections "System V Shared Memory" and "POSIX Shared Memory".

Also, this feature predates Linux, it's been around since 1983 assuming the dates on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V are correct.

Comment: Thank you. I was reading about mmap and I think the fact that mmap has an underlying file supporting it was confusing to me. Shmget has no such underlying file but overall the documentation seems to suggest to use mmap as it is newer api. I will play with shmget and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, mmap() is newer and more widely used, most often for loading common libraries such as libc.so which don't change.  There are some caveats to using shared memory.  Be aware of memory alignment.  Unlike malloc(), you are responsible for putting things in shared memory the right way.  Using shared memory doesn't solve concurrency so if you want to do that you'll have to add semaphores around your shared memory segments which introduces a whole new layer of complexity.  Good Luck!